# How to initialize ASN1ObjectIdentifier from an OID string which contains components larger than int max value?

Tags: java, encoding, bouncycastle, asn.1, ber

I am trying to reference an unregistered ASN.1 Object Identifier which is compliant with the `{joint-iso-itu-t(2) uuid(25)}` arc. I am using the [com.objsys.asn1j.runtime](https://obj-sys.com/docs/acv63/JavaRunTime/com/objsys/asn1j/runtime/Asn1ObjectIdentifier.html) package.

But it seems that the asn1rt library only accepts int[] as identifier. I can't pass the value of the UUID component of the OID string as int as such:

```
    public Asn1ObjectIdentifier getAttributeOID() {
        
        int[] identifierValue = { 2, 25, singleIntegerValue}; // last part is greater than int max
        return new Asn1ObjectIdentifier(identifierValue);
    }
```

I have tried to use the decode method as explained in the objsys.com docs as following:

```
    public Asn1ObjectIdentifier getAttributeOID() {

        //uuid part is converted to integer value from uuid according to ITU-T X.667 Section 6.3 using 

        String oid = "2.25.142312163956071652603888631318689442116"; 
        Asn1BerDecodeBuffer decodeBuffer = new Asn1BerDecodeBuffer(oid.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        Asn1ObjectIdentifier asn1ObjectIdentifier = new Asn1ObjectIdentifier();

        try {
            asn1ObjectIdentifier.decode(decodeBuffer, false, oid.length());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return asn1ObjectIdentifier;
    }
```

However this approach also does not get me the correct identifier value in the resulting object. It outputs something like this:

```
  1.10.46.50.53.46.49.52.50.51.49.50.49.54.51.57.53.54.48.55.49.54.53.50.54.48.51.…
```

I have also failed when trying BouncyCastle to encode the object identifier and then tried to decode it with the api from the `com.objsys.asn1j.runtime` package. Didn't work.

Comment: Which version of BouncyCastle?  The Javadoc for 1.70 does not seem to include the `Asn1ObjectIdentifier(int[])` constructor.

Comment: The library I am trying to use for initializing Asn1ObjectIdentifier is NOT BouncyCastle. It is Obj-Sys Asn1j Runtime. (Asn1rt.jar) I have linked it in the post. I just tried BouncyCastle as a workaround for encoding. If anything is still not clear please let me know, I will update the question.

Comment: I'm curious if there is a new/existing standard that is using the UUID arc?  Or, are you inventing something of your own?

Comment: @Kevin I was trying to define a new OID for my personal project. And the simplest way to define an OID seems to be the unregistered UUID using `{joint-iso-itu-t(2) uuid(25)}`

Answer (score 0):

[Obj-sys documentation](https://obj-sys.com/docs/acv76/JavaHTML/ch05s08.html) shows that the java mapping for OBJECT IDENTIFIER is an array of int (so it's a limitation)

I'm surprised you ask the question here, they have a [contact form](https://obj-sys.com/about/contact.php)

Comment: I was not sure if this was a limitation in the API or my wrong usage of the decode method.